# Using PetaPoco in Asp.NET Core MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, dnx, petapoco, dnx50

so i started trying out the new ASP.NET 5 Platform and have the following dependencies in my Project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "PetaPoco.Core": "5.1.141-beta"
},

"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { "dependencies": { "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5" } },
    "dnxcore50": { "dependencies": { "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5" } }
}
```

Everything builds fine but when i try to access anything from the PetaPoco namespace. Everything fails with the message.

**The type or namespace PetaPoco could not be found, are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference.**

I know what this means but even trying to import the namespace causes the same issue and I can see the library right there in the DNX4.5.1 AND DNX5.0 References

Please what Am i missing here

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you make sure that all packages are restored (i.e. no yellow icon on References)?

Comment: Yep, There are no yellow icons whatsoever on either of references

Comment: A PetaPoco maintainer here. I'm waiting for RC2 before adding support. asp5/dnxcore50 (now ASP.NET CORE 1.0 and.NET CORE 1.0) is missing parts from the ado stack. Plus with all the renaming that going to happening between RC1 and RC2, I feel it'll be better for PP if we wait. That said, I don't see why you can't use it with dnx451 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use PetaPoco with dnx451. However, you'll need to use the compiled [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PetaPoco.Core.Compiled/), as the project structure has changed and the single file deploy won't be copying the source file to a valid location (My guess).

In addition and as per my comment, dnxcore50 (now .Net Core 1.0) is missing a component or two from the ado stack, which means PetaPoco won't work. However, targeting dnx451 should work.

Lastly, we'll mostly likely see PetaPoco builds for .NET/Asp.Net Core 1.0 after they release the RC2.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that PetaPoco won't work with dnxcore50. Remove the following line to try out ASP.NET5 (or asp.net core as the new name is):

```
  "dnxcore50": { "dependencies": { "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5
```

Comment: Tried that, it still did not work even with the absence of the yellow warning icons

Comment: It appears the latest stable build for PetaPoco is not even supported in DNX4.5.1. Looking for some other ORM

Comment: Well, I think it should work, and if you want to try it out you could test "restore packages" when right clicking the references in your solution. A bigger problem is probably that you are using an 8 month old beta. Why not try out the latest Asp net 5/core? Its in RC1 now and supported for production environments. You could use Entity framework with it as well. If you go for RC2 nightly builds I think you can use EF7 which might work with .net core as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/JCKodel/Core.ORM

In the folder __PETAPOCO/XCore there is a functional PetaPoco version that runs on dnxCore. All tests pass.